# connect to another proxy through squid

Tags: 12.10, authentication, cache, squid

i have an HTTPS proxy outside which uses **username/password for authentication** and i want to configure squid on ubuntu 12.10 to direct all connections which are not in it's cache to that proxy. how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [the `cache_peer` directive](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer/) in a configuration like so:

```
cache_peer proxy.example.com parent 8080 0 default no-query login=username:password
```